# Could somebody remind me how to access the WAP browser on the Nokia N73?

Tags: internet

From memory, the Nokia N73 had two web browsers; one WAP browser, and another, fully-functional HTML application. Would somebody be able to remind me what both of these options are labeled as when navigating through the menu of the phone? I think the main web browser was labeled "Web" or similar, but I can't remember what the WAP browser was listed as.

Comment: We don't have the right tags for this question. What tags should we create for it?

Comment: If a cell phone is considered retrocomputing, then I must be getting too old!

Comment: It's more the OS that these devices ran on that could, in a way, be considered retro perhaps? :) In terms of tags - how about "Nokia", "S60" and "Symbian"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [the N73 manual](http://download-support.webapps.microsoft.com/files/support/apac/phones/guides/Nokia_N73-5_APAC_UG_en.pdf) (now available from Microsoft), pages 72 and following.

The HTML browser is called “Web” (“Internet” → “Web”), and the WAP browser is called “Services” (“Internet” → “Services”).